# SQLServer 2014 stored procedure to copy data based on a unique ID not existing in destination

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables, an initial `datafeed` table and a destination table called `livedata`.

I'd like to write a stored procedure to copy records from the `datafeed` table to the `livedata` table if the `livedata` table doesn't contain the record already.

The `datafeed` table has a unique identifier called `IDColumn` which I have created in the `livedata` table too.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: what u have tried so far ?

Comment: I was trying a column by column approach but couldn't get it to function properly. Ended up using SSIS for now but the below comment has solved it

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are the same, then something simple like this will do:

```
create procedure dbo.livedata_import_datafeed as
begin;
  set nocount, xact_abort on;
    insert into dbo.livedata
    select * 
    from datafeed d
    where not exists (
      select 1
      from livedata l
      where l.IDColumn = d.IDColumn 
      )
end;
go
```

Comment: Thanks that worked nicely once I got past an identity issue.